# Can I use this SE to settle arguements?

Tags: discussion

I recently got into an annoying arguement with someone over my phrasing of a comment on another SE site. I'd like to remove identifying parts from it and copy and paste the conversation into a question for this site in order to identify who was in the wrong.

This is purely for my vanity and pride. Would this be OK to post as a question?

Comment: It depends on whether the argument was about something that's actually on-topic here, and it depends on your wording. I'd refrain from copypasting a conversation and simply asking people to take sides. Then you can only have two answers, and a straw poll on them. I'd also refrain from just asking whether your statement on Database Administrators was ambiguous, as that'd be sort of pointless because you already got misunderstood, so you already have all the proof you need that it was ambiguous. You'll have to be careful about what exactly you ask and how you word it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably not. Topics generated from rants and/or arguments don't have a good history of helping anyone other than the asker.

That being said, you *could* ask the question in a way that can help others. Tips:

- Ask a question which will give you an answer filled with information that will solve the core of your argument. As in, don't ask us to resolve your argument. Ask us for the information needed to resolve the argument.
- When asking the question, stop to think if the answers you are likely to get will simply be (a) dictionary definitions of words, (b) notes on differences of style or (c) "it depends". These kinds of answers are boring to read, boring to write and typically show a lack of research on the part of the asker.
- Ask yourself if you are making any assumptions during your argument and make sure you don't make the same assumptions in your question.

Otherwise, you can always poke us in the ELU chat and get some quick, informal opinions.